# PHP Static variable not working as expected

Tags: php, javascript

This [example](http://my.php.net/static) is from php.net:

```
<?php
function Test()
{
    static $a = 0;
    echo $a;
    $a++;
}
?>
```

And this is my code:

```
function getNextQuestionID()
{
    static $idx = 0;
    return $idx++;
}
```

And I use it in JavaScript:

```
'quizID=' + "<?php echo getNextQuestionID(); ?>"
```

Returns 0 everytime. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you misunderstand what static vars do. Try this code and you may understand better:

```
echo getNextQuestionID() . ", " getNextQuestionID() . ", " getNextQuestionID();
```

And you will see what I mean.

The static var only lives as long as the script does.

The reason it is returning 0 on the first run instead of 1 is because you are using the postfix operator $var++ instead of the prefix version - ++$var. The difference is is that the increment only gets applied when using the postfix operator after the function returns - but if you use the prefix operator it is applied before the function returns.

Comment: Sorry I meant returns 0 everytime. I know the difference between post and pre-increment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your data to persist across multiple pages, you need to use [sessions](http://www.php.net/session).

Comment: Even using $_SESSION in the above example will give the same result, ie the variable gets reset at end of script execution. Kinda weird for a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
function getNextQuestionID()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['qNo'])) {
        $_SESSION['qNo'] = 0;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['qNo']++;
    }

    return $_SESSION['qNo'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNextQuestionID()
{
    if (!isset($idx)) {
        static $idx = 0; // OR -1, if you want to start with 0 (ZERO);
    }
    $idx++;
    return $idx;
}

echo getNextQuestionID().'<br />';
echo getNextQuestionID().'<br />';
echo getNextQuestionID().'<br />';
echo getNextQuestionID().'<br />';
```

returns 1,2,3,4

"static" means, the value of the variable is kept as long as your script is running (one website call! to keep it over several website calls, you'll need SESSIONS). If the function gets called more than once, the value is kept and not re-initialised all the time, and thus, incrementable.